# Combine two shapefiles in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-pro, attribute-joins

I have two shapefiles - one contains 3000 polygons representing the electoral divisions of Ireland, and the second contains 18,000 polygons representing the land use classification of Ireland in 2018.

I am using ArcGIS Pro and would like to combine these shapefiles so that I can show the land use per each electoral division.

I have tried summarising the shape_area to give MAX_shape_area of the classifications and then joining to the electoral divisions, but the results are NULL.

Comment: You left out some necessary details, like the coordinate reference system(s) of the layers involved, the exact overlay command (as a Python snippet from geoprocessing Results), and the exact summary command, and what exact join you attempted.

Comment: Make sure to review the field columns so they don't duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'Union' tool.  See:  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/union.htm

> Computes a geometric union of the input features. All features and their attributes will be written to the output feature class.

The result is a polygon feature class where each polygon represents what is unique across BOTH of the input feature classes for that area, and includes all of the attributes of BOTH of the input feature classes.